# Android dynamic listview added position

Tags: android, listview

Hi I am working with android listview.I want to create a dynamic list view in which user can add data dynamically to listview .So far its works fine. Now my problem is my contets are added at start position of listview .I want to add the added contents at last position of list view (like adding comments in facebook post). Is it possible to make ?? Please help me .Thanks in advance :)

MY activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText etInput;
    private Button btnAdd;
    private ListView lvItem;
    private ArrayList<String> itemArrey;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpView();

    }

    private void setUpView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        etInput = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText_input);
        btnAdd = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listView_items);


        itemArrey = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemArrey.clear();

        itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,itemArrey);
        lvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);


        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                addItemList();
            }
        });

        etInput.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    addItemList();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });


    }

    protected void addItemList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (isInputValid(etInput)) {
        itemArrey.add(0,etInput.getText().toString());
        etInput.setText("");

        itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }   

    }

    protected boolean isInputValid(EditText etInput2) {
        // TODO Auto-generatd method stub
        if (etInput2.getText().toString().trim().length()<1) {
            etInput2.setError("Please Enter Item");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: itemArrey.add(0,etInput.getText().toString()); remove 0 from the start. Do not specify position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove **position** from

> itemArrey.add(0,etInput.getText().toString()); // Position=0

Try this way.

```
 itemArrey.add(etInput.getText().toString());
```

that directly add your string at the end.

Comment: I have one more dbt, How to add in the case of custom adapter ?

Comment: @PrinceThomas Just add new items in your `ArrayList` and called  `itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();;`

Comment: I used custom adapter extends base adapter. my set listview code like this  l1.setAdapter(new dataListAdapter(name_array,comment_array,time_array,img_array));  then how can i update listview ?

Comment: these 4 parameters are array list.and I get data to updated in these array list the how to update bcoz I cannot get adapter directly to use nofifyDatachanged method

Comment: @PrinceThomas Sorry! but i do not understand what are you talking about? Please post your another questions with some code...

Comment: yaa finally i added  notifyDataSetChanged() in my constructor and its works fine :)

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying position to add new element to. Just avoid using position and new item will be added at the end of list.

```
itemArrey.add( etInput.getText().toString() );
```

Further more, you might also like to scroll down to this newly added item. So you can use these in xml

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
```

or use `setSelection()` to do so like -

```
lvItem.setSelection(countOfItems-1);
```